# Why the request of Invoices - List By Billing Subscription in Azure through the "try it" gives a 404?

Tags: azure, billing

Thanks in advance :) I performed a request of this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/2019-10-01-preview/invoices/list-by-billing-subscription#code-try-0) with these parameters and it is answered 404. Can anyone give me a clue about what I am doing wrong? I am performing it with my user who is the owner of this personal account. Also, we performed this in a business account because we know this info is not available to every subscription. We performed this with an user who has billing reader permissions but it also gives 404.

- billingAccountName: find in Cost Management + Billing > Properties
- billingSubscriptionName: the id of the subscription name

```
GET https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingAccounts/{billingAccountName}/billingSubscriptions/{billingSubscriptionName}/invoices?api-version=2019-10-01-preview&periodEndDate=2022-06-01&periodStartDate=2022-06-30
```

```
cache-control: no-cache
content-length: 0
date: Fri, 24 Jun 2022 09:31:35 GMT
expires: -1
mise-correlation-id: de3c5cae-0644-43c1-9941-dd675e595f2a
pragma: no-cache
x-frame-options: DENY
x-ms-correlation-request-id: b4d8cb29-13e9-4795-b17b-8d0eafea4d3e
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-tenant-reads: 11994
x-ms-request-id: b4d8cb29-13e9-4795-b17b-8d0eafea4d3e
x-ms-routing-request-id: FRANCECENTRAL:20220624T093135Z:b4d8cb29-13e9-4795-b17b-8d0eafea4d3e
x-ms-service-version: 10.6.1992.510
```

Comment: For the APIs to have access to the invoice data, we must grant them permissions via the Azure portal.

Comment: Navigate to Azure Portal => Cost Management + Billing=> Your Subscription => Invoices =>Access to invoice => Select On => Save

Comment: No :( it didn't. Thank you so much again, and also for asking me :) I think it didn't because I couldn't follow these steps strictly: I navigated to the Azure Portal => Cost Management + Billing but I found no way of clicking any place called "Save". First of all, in the left navigation pane I found no tab called strictly "Your subscription" but one called Azure Subscriptions. Do you refer to this? But in this tab there is no place of click save. There is also one tab called invoices, if I click there I can "access to my invoice" and select on it but didn't find a "save"@HarshithaVeeramalla-MT

Comment: But I tried all the other options available there: I downloaded the invoice as a csv and click in prepare usage file. Then try the request but it didn't work :( I did all this with my personal account, I'm going to wait for my colleague to repeat the steps on the business account

Comment: I'm going to put the complete 404 answer in case it can help

Comment: Refer this images to navigate [Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwpAO.png) [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBEjt.png)

Comment: Your Subscription has to be pay-as-you-go

Comment: Yes you need to select  that  `Azure Subscriptions` tab only

Comment: Thank you so much @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT! I tried this in my [personal azure account](https://imgur.com/a/kn1Cd24) and it seems there is no way of activating this, as this "access to my invoice" didn't appear. I'm waiting for my colleague to try this in the business account

Comment: @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT in this enterprise account following these steps it appears this error [enterprise account](https://imgur.com/xOgQ0CN). "There are no billing relationship setup yet". We followed the provider tutorial to setup this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/mca-setup-account), but found no way to link this both.

Comment: Also, we discovered in the payment method and billing profile tabs it does not appear anything. But is is so strange because we are Billing owner so we have the higher permissions to see billing, isn't it? Which permissions do you have over this account? Are you able to see anything on these tabs? If so, we are gonna ask our manager telling there must be something not setup regarding the payment method. But it is so strange there is a billing account but no payment method setup

Comment: Are you sure it is a pay-as-you-go subscription ?

Comment: Invoices are only available for billing accounts, billing profiles, and pay-as-you-go subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, it was so helpful for me! Thank so much @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT Mmm although I cannot still make the request. How can I check the subscription is paid-as-you-go? We looked where the docu says (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/switch-azure-offer) [subscription](https://imgur.com/ubhMxyB) but neither any info appeared nor did the ability to switch subscription type.

Comment: Mmmm which role do you have? Only the billing owner? We only have the billing owner and cannot access the cost, for example [access denied](https://imgur.com/hnVJB8B)

Comment: it seems we need more permissions but we did not find any tutorial of azure specifying which ones we need :(

Comment: Check with the one who is having Azure pay-as-you-go subscription

Comment: Thanks @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT! I just checked with this one, I know it is a pay-as-you-go subscription because I received some billings, but in the overview tab it appears the same info as in the overview of the subscription as in the enterprise subscription I sent an image. So it does o clarify if it is or not

Comment: Yes, but I totally agree it seems I cannot access to invoice because this account is not a pay-as-you-go subscription

Comment: I'm going to try link a payment method to the account and then retry the request. Thank you so much for your help and your time @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the request of Invoices - List By Billing Subscription in Azure through the "try it" gives a 404?

- If you are using a free Azure membership, you cannot view the invoice details.
- Invoices are  available only for billing accounts, billing profiles, and pay-as-you-go subscriptions.
- In Azure Active Directory, check your role

Navigate to Azure Portal => Azure Active Directory => Roles and administrators

[image]

- To know the role

Navigate to the Azure portal => Your Resource Group => Access Control (IAM)

[image]

- Check whether you can give access to the Invoice
- For the APIs to have access to the invoice data, we must grant them permissions via the Azure portal.
  Navigate to Azure Portal => Cost Management + Billing=> Your Subscription => Invoices =>Access to invoice => Select On => Save

[image]

[image]

[image]

- I am having the Contributor Role, when I try to access the Invoice  got the below Message

[image]

Comment: Mmm I did not click this yet because I'm waiting my manager to link a payment method to the subscription so it turns into a pay-as-you-go and I can check if this tab of "access to my invoice" now appears. But, you helped me so much,s o although I could not validate this make the request to be 200 I'm going to click in the checkmark, and afterwards when I get the pay-as-you subscription check this. And if something did not work comment later. Thank you so much :)